# mod_rewrite force lowercase urls

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting, lowercase

i've searched the net for an answer to my problem without any luck, so her goes:

I'm redoing my mod_rewrite for SEO purposes and i want all urls to be lowercase, for instance:

```
http://BLAbla.com/
```

becomes

```
http://bla.com/
```

currently my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ([\w]*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]?)$ index.php?worker=$1&params=$2 [L]
```

but when i run http://localhost/site/ i get error 500. I only know basic reg ex, and very limited mod_rewrite, so i cannot se the error here. If i remove the rewritemap line, the page doesn't give any error. Is rewritemap not supported by my server or something??

Any other comments regarding the .htaccess file are very very welcome :)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Esben

Rewriting the hostname is a bit trickier.  Do you have access to the server error log?  Because that may some using information about the cause of the 500.

It's a good idea to enclose the parameters in quotation marks just for clarity:

```
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "[A-Z]"
RewriteRule "(.*)"           "${lc:$1}" [R=301,L]
```

The `[L]` is going to force this to end processing for this request, which means that if there's more work to be done to the URI, it'll happen when the request is re-submitted.  You might want to consider batching your modifications so requests only go through the munging process once:

```
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "[A-Z]"
RewriteRule "(.*)"           "${lc:$1}" [E=REDIRECT:TRUE]

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^www\."  [NC]
RewriteRule "^"              "-"        [E=REDIRECT:TRUE,E=PREFIX_WWW:TRUE]
```

What is the following trying to do?

```
RewriteRule ([\w]*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The effect (despite the funky regex) is 'If the REQUEST_URI ends in a '`/`', strip it off and redirect.'  Is that what you want?  Bear in mind that things are a little different in a `.htaccess` file..

And this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]?)$ index.php?worker=$1&params=$2 [L]
```

It looks like you're trying to say 'Change any "foo/bar" into "index.php?worker=foo&params=bar"'.  If that's correct, it's probably not going to work.  Since you're in a `.htaccess` file, you're matching against the filesystem path, *not* the URI.

So try this:

```
RewriteMap  "lc"                 "int:tolower"

RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}"     "[A-Z]"
RewriteRule "(.*)"               "${lc:$1}" [E=REDIRECT:TRUE]

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"       "!^www\."  [NC]
RewriteRule "^"                  "-"         [E=REDIRECT:TRUE,E=PREFIX_WWW:TRUE]

RewriteCond "${ENV:REDIRECT}"    "!TRUE"
RewriteRule "^"                  "-"        [SKIP=2]
RewriteCond "${ENV:PREFIX_WWW}"  "TRUE"
RewriteRule "(.*)"               "http://www.${HTTP_HOST}/$1"     [R=301,L]
RewriteRule "^"                  "-"                               [R=301,L]

RewriteRule "^([^/]+)/([^/]?)$"  "index.php?worker=$1&params=$2" [PT]
```

I'm not sure about the effect of `SKIP` on `RewriteCond` statements mixed with `RewriteRule`s, but give the above a try and see if you're any closer.